# Как узнать используется ли js библиотека или файл?

Tags: javascript, css, оптимизация

Есть сайт. Много подключенных JS и CSS файлов. Зашел вопрос об оптимизации. Задался вопросом, как определить используется и где тот или иной JS, CSS файл. Подскажите пожалуйста, такое возможно?

Comment: нужно отключить все, и по одному подключать и смотреть что изменилось

Answer (score 2):

Напишите в нужном файле или/и в нужном фрагменте код `console.log("some text");`.

Если в консоли браузера выведется текст, который вы написали, значит используется, в противном - нет.